# View PDF as a SlideShow?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, pdf

I'm looking for an answer, if there is somehow possible to view a PDF file (ASP.NET MVC 3 project) in other way like a standard in the adobe plugin. My client wants to:

- show the PDF file like a slide show (or navigate horizontally through the pages)
- protect the PDF file from being downloaded

so, maybe there is a JavaScript/jQuery control to change the presentation of the PDF or maybe some other way ? Is it even possible ? Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

Google has an open PDF viewer.  Trying it out:

https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=www.graphpad.com/manuals/prism4/StatisticsGuide.pdf